MgCl2·6H2O for growing crystals?
I am wondering if I can use "magnesium oil" (sold as a health supplement spray, ingredients listed as magnesium chloride hexahydrate and purified water) to grow crystals as an at home science demo for kids, and if so what steps would be needed to prepare the solution before starting.

It would seem that what you need to do is boil most of the water off. Using a liquid health supplement seems an expensive way of carrying out such an experiment for kids. Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a cheaper material like sodium chloride table salt, or magnesium sulfate Epsom salt, and add the water yourself?

Sodium chloride seldom forms crystals bigger than few mm. Better is copper sulfate or alums (aluminium, chromium), that can form crystals of size several cm.

@poutnik from what I see online sodium chloride grows much better without anticaking agent. It does come out fast which doesn't give time for big crystals. Once you've made a saturated solution, the slower you cool it, the better the crystals will likely be. Epsom salt gives nice long crystals. Copper sulfate could have safety issues as it's toxic if eaten (they let me play with it as a kid but rules are ridiculous now.) Alums are very good but vary in toxicity. I did alums at school aged about 12 and we got about 1cm in the first crystallizaton. We transferred to a new beaker to keep growing.

Al, Cr, Fe alums are isomorphic, so one can  let grow one on another. Sure, if security is major concern, it is better to stay at sodium or magnesium.

MgCl2 . 6 H2O is hygroscopic. If relative humidity is above 33%, the saturated solution does not evaporate, but absorbs aerial humidity.

Sure, Calcium chloride is completely out as it is deliquescent (absorbs so much water it dissolves in it, spontaneously changing from crystals to liquid.) I doubt humidity would be over 33% indoors unless you're in the tropics. Hygroscopy could a disadvantage or an advantage (very slow evaporation making crystals grow slower.) I've never heard of anyone using magnesium chloride for this experiment though.

As mentioned, MgCl2 is so deliquescent that open containers of the solid (crystals) often turn to liquid by absorption of moisture. Try MgSO4, Epsom salt, instead.

Thanks all! Seems like the answer is yes, if concentrated, I could try growing crystals, though it's not the ideal material. I might give it a go anyway - my motivation is mainly having nothing else to do with this solution :)
